# Is it possible to get Mac Address of user's when creating new record?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is it possible to get the MAC address of a user that posts a new record?
If I had column called `mac_address`, how can I write my controller to put the MAC address into that column?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A user's mac address is not part of the web request.

I know it's not your question, but you can get their IP address using the request object:

```
request.ip
```

In your `create` action, you could have something like the following (assuming you have a column `ip_address`):

```
def create
  @item = Item.new(params[:item])
  @item.ip_address = request.ip
  if @item.save
    ...
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks. what if I use Jquery? Can I obtain Mac Address?

Comment: @cat you cannot. The browser doesn't expose that sort of information from the host.

Answer (score 7):

You can take the `request.ip` and call a ping on it. This should put the ip in your machine's arp cache. By dumping the arp cache you can match the MAC Address.

```
`ping -c 1 #{request.ip}`
sleep(10) # For dramatic effect
arptable = `arp -a`
entries = arptable.split("\n")
ipmap = {}
entries.each do |e|
  ent = e.split(" ")
  ipmap["#{ent[1].gsub(/\(|\)/, "")}"] = ent[3]
end
puts ipmap["#{request.ip}"]
```

This code is tested on osx mavericks, tools and formatting may vary on linux/bsd/solaris but should be the same approach, the other caveat is that it will only work on your local intranet / network segment.

## Update

Checked on amazon linux and the formatting seems the same.