# Ruby on rails get mac address

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mac-address

I want to get mac address from user in a form, but I don't know is there a simple way to get it, or I have to get with using 6 text field.

### Update:

> Jquery

```
$(document).on('ready page:load', function() {
   $('.field-id').mask('00:00:00:00:00:00', {'translation': {0: {pattern: /[a-z0-9]/}}});
```

});

> Form view

```
<%= f.text_field :comp_id, class: "field-id" %>
```

I don't understand why it is not working

Comment: Looks like answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14175695/is-it-possible-to-get-mac-address-of-users-when-creating-new-record

Comment: No, I want to get it from user, not get it automatically

Comment: btw when I use request.ip, I get only '::1', it didn't return the ip address, maybe because I try to get as string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jQuery for client-side input mask. Here is the jQuery plugin just for this: http://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/

In case of MAC address, the field masking might look like this:

```
$('#field-id').mask('00:00:00:00:00:00', {'translation': {0: {pattern: /[a-z0-9]/}}});
```

Comment: `<%= f.text_field :comp_id, id: "field-id" %>` is it wrong ?

Comment: If you use standard ActionView helpers, then it's ok.

Comment: @RamazanZor What do you mean? Did you add plugin too?

Comment: Here's the source code for plugin https://github.com/igorescobar/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/tree/master/dist or you can use bower package as well.

Comment: I didn't add any plugin